# Play audio audio file at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 images, each has an audio file that plays when the image is clicked.

I want the audio that is playing for one image to stop when another image is clicked and then play the audio for that image.

```
$('.cl').click(function() {
  var DOMElem = $('.cs').get(0);
  DOMElem.paused ? DOMElem.play() : DOMElem.pause();
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
</br>
<audio class="cs">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
</br>
<audio class="cs">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
</br>
<audio class="cs">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: the is this [muted tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_muted.asp) which you can apply to the one which is playing.

Comment: can u write the code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting first `audio` object every time. You need to get the `object` with respect to `img`

```
$('.cl').click(function () {
   var DOMElem = $(this).next().next().get(0);
   DOMElem.paused ? DOMElem.play() : DOMElem.pause();
});
```

A better approach is to make a container div for each image and audio and when you click the `image` you can get the audio object with respect to container.

```
<div class="audioContainer">
        <img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
        </br>
        <audio class="cs">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="audioContainer">
        <img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
        </br>
        <audio class="cs">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="audioContainer">
        <img class="cl" src="photo/198.jpg" />
        </br>
        <audio class="cs">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
    <script>

         var DOMElem;
    $('.cl').click(function () {
        if (DOMElem) {
            if (!DOMElem.paused)
                DOMElem.pause();
        }
        DOMElem = $(this).parent().find('.cs').get(0);
        DOMElem.play();
        console.log(DOMElem);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: but when clicked on the other image first audio is not going to pause

Comment: Ok make the variable `DOMElem` global i will edit answer to show you at very last script.

Comment: same result no change and updated the code but no result

Comment: @banuprakash please see answer now i have made one change